A little trick with infinite union and complement
Let $X$ be a set, I want to show that
$$A_n\subseteq B_n\subseteq X, \hspace{5pt} \forall n\in \mathbb{N} \Longrightarrow \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}B_n \setminus \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}A_n=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(B_n\setminus A_n)$$
Here's my attempt:
$$\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}B_n \setminus \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}A_n=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}B_n \cap \left(X\setminus \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}A_n \right)=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}B_n\cap \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(X\setminus A_n) $$
Now I can't see where to go to conclude, any help?

What you're trying to show is false.

Take e.g. $X = {\star}, A_0 = \varnothing, B_0 = X$ and $A_n = X, B_n = X$ for $n \neq 0$, then $\bigcup B_n \setminus \bigcup A_n = \varnothing$ but $\bigcup (B_n \setminus A_n) = X$.

I'm trying to understand what you're saying by picking an example with just two sets:
Consider $A_1 = [0,4]$, $B_1 = [0,2]$ and $A_2 = [-4, 0]$, $B_2 = [-1, 0]$.
Then $(A_1 - B_1) \cup (A_2 - B_2) = (3,4] \cup [-4, -1) = [-4, -1) \cup (3, 4]$.
On the other hand, $(A_1 \cup A_2) - (B_1 \cup B_2) = [-4, 4] - [-1, 2] = [-4, -1) \cup (2, 4]$.
These two sets are not equal; your claim is false!

(My A's and B's are switched from what you wrote, but hopefully that doesn't impede the argument!)

Ok thank you. My problem is to show that the measure of that difference of unions is zero knowing that $\mu(B_n\setminus A_n)=0$ forall $n$. For this I tried to prove that equivalence, which is false as you said.

@SigmaAlgebra If your question is different than the one posted above – and your comment, which includes a measurement, $\mu$, suggests that this is the case – then it will be well-advised to post a new question in which you ask exactly that which you want to know. It's still important to include the work that you have done or how you have tried to reason through the problem, but you definitely want all givens to be included in the setup!

Okok, I will post another question.
